Recursion regarding number-partitions
I am learning about partitions of numbers at the moment.
Definition:
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. A $k$-partition of $n$ is a representation of $n$ as the sum of $k$ numbers greater than $0$, (i.e.
$n=a_1+...+a_k$, where $a_i>0$ for all $0 \leq i \leq k $), such that the order of the summands doesn't matter.
We will denote such a partition of $n$ as $k$-tuple $(a_1,...,a_k)$.
For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we can consider the number of (all) $k$- partitions of $n$, which we will denote as $p(n)$.
Further let p(n,k) denote the number of all $m$-partitions of $n$ where all summands are less or equal to $k$, i.e. we want to count all $m$-partitions of $n$ for $0 \leq m \leq n $ such that the highest summand of a partition is less or equal to $k$.
Now I want to show the following recursion regarding
$p(n,k)$:
p(n,0)= $1$ if $n=0$ and $=0$ if $n>0$
$p(n,1)=1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$p(n,k)=p(n)$ if $k \geq n$
$p(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\rfloor} p(n-ij,i-1)$.
The first 3 points are obvious. I am interested in the 4th point.
I do not really know to show this. My only gues was to try induction, but this didnt work. I would be very happy if someone could show me.

To clarify, you defined a $k-$partition, but then never used it anywhere else? EG Maybe you wanted "the number of (all) $\color{red}{k-}$partitions of $n$"?

@CalvinLin Thanks for the comment, I edited it.

Likewise, can you clarify if you want $p(n,k)$ to count $k-$partitions? $\quad$ If no, then it's unclear to me why this definition was introduced, since all that you care about are partitions. (It might be that this definition isn't relevant to your questions at all) $\quad$  If yes, then $p(2, 1) \neq 1$.

@CalvinLin I didn't know how to approach this problem, so I thought I write down the definition that might be of relevance. I did another edit. I hope it makes sense now.

We take all of the partitions counted by $p(n,k)$, and divide them up according to their greatest part. Then, for each $i\in \{1,\dots,k\}$, we take all of the partitions whose greatest part is $i$, and further divide them up according to the number of times that $i$ appears as a part.
Now, let us enumerate all of the sub-sub-divisions. Of the partitions $n$ where each part has size at most $k$, how many have a largest part equal to $i$, and have this part repeated exactly $j$ times? The answer is just $p(n-ij,i-1)$. Indeed, if you remove the $j$ copies of the part of size $i$, then the remaining parts will sum up to $n-ij$. Since we stipulated that $i$ was the largest part, and we removed all copies of $i$, the remaining parts will all be of size at most $i-1$.
Finally, the rule of sum implies that summing $p(n-ij,i-1)$ over all possible $i$ and $j$ must add up to $p(n,k)$.
